# Redirect while server is working

Tags: asp.net, web

I have a asp.net website.
Every day at, let's say, 8pm the server executes some operations which last 20 minutes.
My question is: how can i redirect the users who access my website during this time to another page on the server? Multithreading?

Answer (score 1):

A easy way is just to redirect them depending on the time. Use global.asax and implement the function in Application_BeginRequest method.

Maybe not the best solution but a easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

An option without modifying your app code is to have a scheduled task that renames the App_Offline.htm file back and forwards during your busy time (Assuming you want to say 'site is busy' or something similar)

i.e. at 8pm run a  .bat file such as

```
ren d:\webapp\_App_Offline.htm App_Offline.htm
```

At 8:20pm run

```
ren d:\webapp\App_Offline.htm _App_Offline.htm
```

Not clever, certainly not foolproof but an idea nonetheless that is easy to implement quickly.